# Pygame display surface error

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

I have the following problem in pygame.I got pygame surface using`surf=pygame.display.get_ surface()`
,but when I am trying to call

```
surf.fill()
```

It says:

```
None type have no attribute fill
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a display mode first with [`pygame.display.set_mode`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode).

Otherwise, [`pygame.display.get_surface()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface) will return `None`:

> **pygame.display.get_surface()**
>   *Get a reference to the currently set display surface*
>   `get_surface() -> Surface`
>   Return a reference to the currently set display Surface. If no display mode has been set this will return None.

Also, you usually don't need that function, since `set_mode` already returns the display `Surface`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method "fill()" needs a color argument:

fill()
fill Surface with a solid color
fill(color, rect=None, special_flags=0) -> Rect

the documentation:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill

Comment: You are right but that error will only occur after the `NoneType` error was fixed